# How to disable angular's $templateCache completely

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In our project we're using a lot of directives. The partials of those directives are defined with `templateUrl`. Now, we have directives that need to be loaded and reevaluated every time the user executes an action on the screen.

One use case:

- The user logs in as admin and does something
- The user logs out as admin and proceeds doing something else
- The user logs in with his personal account

Every time those actions are executed every directive template should be loaded newly in order to show correct UI elements.

Unfortunately

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, next, current) {  
    // clear cache to trigger reloading
    // (server decides if has permission or not)
    if(next && next.templateUrl) {
      if($templateCache.get(next.templateUrl)) {
        $templateCache.remove(next.templateUrl);
        console.log('removed: '+next.templateUrl);
      };
    };
  });
```

in angular's run method doesn't do the job as it is only called on `stateChange` and is not concerned with directive templates.

Also, continous `$templateCache.removeAll` calls don't seem to be working either.
So, is there a way (or workaround) to disable caching of partials/templates altogether?

Comment: I'm sorry but that smells like bad design, why invalidating cache of something that has to be loaded again? I mean you load same template twice, what would be the difference in display? Provide a fiddle or plunker with the case please

Comment: Yes @maurycy is right. You don't need to disable the cache, you can achieve the same in different way.

Comment: Don't you think that if you're going to say "don't do that" that you should provide an alternative?  Your comments are completely unhelpful, and, speaking as someone trying to solve a problem with template caching, wasted my time in this coming up in a search.